# where is getItemCount() return to

Tags: android, android-recyclerview, android-adapter, android-viewholder

I'm trying to understand where the `RecyclerView.Adapter` receives the result from `getItemCount()` and determine whether or not there are any items to show. The documentation says

> this method returns the total number of items in the data set held by
>   the adapter

but I dont see the logic in the `RecyclerView.java` class where it would not show anything.
To give some context, I wanted to display an emptystate on my recycler view...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`int getItemCount ()` is Whatever data set while setting to the adapter it returns the count of that.

If used recyclerview with header then need to return total dataset plus one.

This is recyclerview overrided method it will return dataset count.

Answer (score 0):

`getItemCount()` returns the total number of items in the data set held by the adapter to recyclarview. The count will be received by the model class of the recyclarview.

Please refer to:
https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v7/widget/RecyclerView.Adapter#getitemcount